# Regex to find a String that is not in a word

Tags: regex

I have lots of files with lots of text. In those files, I'm looking for a string, let's say "av" that is not surrounded by any letter (a-zA-Z), like in hAVing. No case sensitive. My tool supports perl compatible syntax.

Some examples:
Match: av
Match: av-link
Match: let's AV something
Match: av/dc
Match: ab,ac,av,az
NO Match: having 
NO Match: average
NO Match: textav

Comment: Read a document on regular expressions this should be pretty straightforward to do. Or do you have a specific problem?

Comment: I tried the following, but that matches only on "av" but not on anything else like ".av"    [^a-zA-Z]av[^a-zA-Z],

Answer (score 0):

This expression should help you: `/\bav\b/uim`

Comment: yes, that's perfect, thank you! (For all: Please not, that despite the limitation to a-zA-Z in my request, this also doesn't match with 0-9 before or after the string. That was good for me, but might not fulfill your demands.)

Answer (score 0):

Try "not a letter" lookarounds:

```
(?<![a-zA-Z])av(?![a-zA-Z])
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/eK7lK6/1

Answer (score -2):

In regex, the ^ character is a not
    ^[a-zA-Z]av^[a-zA-Z]

Comment: That is not true. (Which is also not the same as `[^true]`, by the way.)